# Returning Data table from a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, datatable

I am new to WCF.

Which is the best way to return data from WCF service when using a datatable as the source.

Answer (score 1):

Data can be returned any number of ways from a web service.

The most popular are [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) and [JSON](http://www.json.org/).